# How to add lazy field in content endpoint using Gutenberg blocks

Tags: filters, block-editor

I'm trying to add a "lazy" field to the "content" endpoint using "rest_prepare_post".

I do this by adding "rest_prepare_post" filter. 
Then I check if "$post->post_content" has gutenberg blocks. 
After that I search in the loop all those that have blockName set as "core/image". 
Then I edit the contents of this block.

My problem is to put a changed HTML into "content" field, which will be a copy of "content[rendered]".
Below I insert the code.

```php
<?php
class EndpointLazyLoading
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', [ $this, 'add_content_lazy_field' ], 1, 3);
    }

    public function add_content_lazy_field($response, $post, $request)
    {
        if (has_blocks($post->post_content)) {
            $blocks = parse_blocks($post->post_content);

            foreach ($blocks as &$block) {
                if (isset($block['blockName']) && $block['blockName'] === 'core/image') {
                    // some magic with $block['innerContent'][0] and $block['innerHTML']
                }
            }
            unset($block);

            $response->data['content']['lazy'] = [
                'markup'  => post_password_required($post) 
                    ? '' 
                    : '^^^^^^^^content that i try to add^^^^^^^^',
                'protected' => (bool) $post->post_password
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

I want to see something like this:

```
GET domain.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/6222?_lazy
{
    "id": 6222,
        (...),
    "content": {
        "rendered": "original content",
        "protected": false,
        "lazy": {
            "markup": "original content with changed image block (wp:image block)"
        }
    },
        (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before your `$response->data[...` to render changed blocks

```
$markup = '';
foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
    $markup .= render_block( $block );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :)